# Reduce Capture Video Size in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone application where I need to upload video file on server captured from camera. But when I upload it on server it takes too much time to upload due to large video file size. I used Nokia Lumia 800 (Windows Phone 7 OS) which has 8megapixel camera and which captured around 100MB video file in 60 second.

So due to this my upload time is too large. Can any one suggest me how I can reduce video file size, I don't want high quality video.

Comment: See How do you compress captured video in Silverlight? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134553/how-do-you-compress-captured-video-in-silverlight

Comment: I am also having same problem but in my case I am not able to upload video. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239160/file-uploading-not-working-on-win-phone-8-3g-connection